# Orcale behavior with left outer join with or condition

Tags: oracle, left-join, oracle12c

I recently run into an oddity in Oracle12c(12.2.0.1) behavior with or-conditional left joins.

We have two schematically identical databases, with small differences in data, one being test-environment database and other being production database. Optimizer parameters are the same in both databases.

Given the query is:

```
SELECT A.Id as ObjectID,A.GlobalId as GlobalId,A.Type as Type,
(SELECT listagg(CLASS, ',') within group (order by CLASS) from D_VIEW D_SEPARATE_QUERY 
 where D_SEPARATE_QUERY.A_ID = A.OBJECTID) as D_CLASS_LIST, 
Max(CASE WHEN (D.REASON = 1) Then 1 Else 0 END) as CONDITION_1,
Max(CASE WHEN (D.REASON in  (2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 504)) Then 1 Else 0 END) as CONDITION_2
FROM A_VIEW A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B_VIEW B on B.A_GLOBALID = A.GLOBALID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN C_VIEW C on C.B_GLOBALID = B.GLOBALID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN D_VIEW D on
    D.C_ID = C.OBJECTID or 
    D.A_ID = A.OBJECTID

WHERE 1 = 1 AND A.TYPE=:TYPE0 
GROUP BY A.ObjectID
```

In out test environment the execution plan for this looks like:

---

```
| Id  | Operation                                | Name                | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |                     |   207K|   439M|       |  5109M  (4)|110:52:41 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                           |                     |   207K|   439M|  4872M|  5109M  (4)|110:52:41 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN OUTER                       |                     |  2182K|  4631M|       |  5108M  (4)|110:52:15 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN OUTER                       |                     |  2182K|  4604M|   449M|   290K  (2)| 00:00:23 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN OUTER                      |                     |  2182K|   424M|   113M|   244K  (2)| 00:00:20 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN OUTER                     |                     |   741K|   104M|    41M| 56975   (2)| 00:00:05 |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| A                   |   610K|    34M|       | 37393   (2)| 00:00:03 |
|*  7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | I1439TYPE           |  1627K|       |       |  2801   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN               | IDX$$_973C0001      |  2785K|   236M|       |  6227   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |      VIEW                                | index$_join$_009    |  7908K|   422M|       |   159K  (2)| 00:00:13 |
|* 10 |       HASH JOIN                          |                     |       |       |       |            |          |
|* 11 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IDX$$_973C0002      |  7908K|   422M|       | 54686   (2)| 00:00:05 |
|* 12 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN              | GDB_CT2_265         |  7908K|   422M|       | 67651   (2)| 00:00:06 |
|  13 |     VIEW                                 | VW_SSQ_1            |   285K|   547M|       |  3965   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |      SORT GROUP BY                       |                     |   285K|  2511K|    19M|  3965   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                  | D                   |   995K|  8753K|       |  2320   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |    BUFFER SORT                           |                     |     1 |    13 |       |  5109M  (4)|110:52:41 |
|  17 |     VIEW                                 | VW_LAT_DAF4C663     |     1 |    13 |       |  2340   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|* 18 |      TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | D                   |     1 |   121 |       |  2340   (3)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("ITEM_1"(+)="OBJECTID")
   4 - access("B_GLOBALID"(+)="GLOBALID")
   5 - access("A_GLOBALID"(+)="GLOBALID")
   6 - filter("GDB_TO_DATE"=TIMESTAMP' 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000000')
   7 - access("TYPE"=TO_NUMBER(:TYPE0))
   8 - filter("GDB_TO_DATE"(+)=TIMESTAMP' 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000000')
  10 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  11 - access("GDB_TO_DATE"=TIMESTAMP' 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000000')
  12 - filter("GDB_TO_DATE"=TIMESTAMP' 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000000')
  18 - filter("D"."A_ID"="OBJECTID" OR "D"."C_ID"="OBJECTID")
```

And production environment execution plan:

```
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                 | Name                | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                          |                     |   303K|   643M|       |    14M  (1)| 00:18:57 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY                            |                     |   303K|   643M|     9G|    14M  (1)| 00:18:57 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN OUTER                        |                     |  4509K|  9568M|       |    13M  (1)| 00:18:03 |
|*  3 |    HASH JOIN OUTER                        |                     |  2254K|  4756M|   464M|   310K  (2)| 00:00:25 |
|*  4 |     HASH JOIN OUTER                       |                     |  2254K|   438M|   121M|   257K  (2)| 00:00:21 |
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN OUTER                      |                     |   797K|   112M|    43M| 62800   (2)| 00:00:05 |
|*  6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED | A                   |   643K|    36M|       | 41711   (2)| 00:00:04 |
|*  7 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | I1439TYPE           |  1830K|       |       |  3213   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |       INDEX FAST FULL SCAN                | IDX$$_973C0001      |  2965K|   251M|       |  6889   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |      VIEW                                 | index$_join$_009    |  8125K|   433M|       |   166K  (2)| 00:00:14 |
|* 10 |       HASH JOIN                           |                     |       |       |       |            |          |
|* 11 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN                   | IDX$$_973C0002      |  8125K|   433M|       | 56959   (1)| 00:00:05 |
|* 12 |        INDEX FAST FULL SCAN               | GDB_CT2_265         |  8125K|   433M|       | 70534   (2)| 00:00:06 |
|  13 |     VIEW                                  | VW_SSQ_1            |   334K|   640M|       |  4902   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|  14 |      SORT GROUP BY                        |                     |   334K|  2939K|    23M|  4902   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|  15 |       TABLE ACCESS FULL                   | D                   |  1203K|    10M|       |  2926   (3)| 00:00:01 |
|  16 |    BUFFER SORT                            |                     |     2 |    26 |       |    14M  (1)| 00:18:57 |
|  17 |     VIEW                                  | VW_LAT_DAF4C663     |     2 |    26 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |      VIEW                                 | VW_ORE_DF336D34     |     2 |    26 |       |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |       UNION-ALL                           |                     |       |       |       |            |          |
|  20 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| D                   |     1 |     9 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 21 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | G1126CID            |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 22 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| D                   |     1 |    15 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 23 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | G1126AID            |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   3 - access("ITEM_1"(+)="OBJECTID")
   4 - access("B_GLOBALID"(+)="GLOBALID")
   5 - access("A_GLOBALID"(+)="GLOBALID")
   6 - filter("GDB_TO_DATE"=TIMESTAMP' 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000000')
   7 - access("TYPE"=TO_NUMBER(:TYPE0))
   8 - filter("GDB_TO_DATE"(+)=TIMESTAMP' 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000000')
  10 - access(ROWID=ROWID)
  11 - access("GDB_TO_DATE"=TIMESTAMP' 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000000')
  12 - filter("GDB_TO_DATE"=TIMESTAMP' 9999-12-31 23:59:59.000000000')
  21 - access("D"."C_ID"="OBJECTID")
  22 - filter(LNNVL("D"."C_ID"="OBJECTID"))
  23 - access("D"."A_ID"="OBJECTID")
```

As you can see, our production Oracle actually understands that last left joins' or-condition can be expanded, and performs a lnnvl-filter for indexed access on both conditions which should be always ALOT more effective than full table access with our data volumes. Our test environment Oracle doesn't seem to think so and always goes on with full table scan for last join,
which absolutely wrecks performance of the query, up to around x100 times slower execution.

Where this difference in behavior could come from?

P.S I know that or-conditioned left join can be rewritten into two separate joins for indexed access on both conditions, but at the moment I'm more inclined to figure out the reason behind the difference in behavior and if it's fixable in Oracle itself.

**UPDATE 1:**

SHOW PARAMETERS OPTIMIZER:

```
NAME                                               TYPE        VALUE                                                                                                
-------------------------------------------------- ----------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
optimizer_adaptive_plans                           boolean     TRUE                                                                                                 
optimizer_adaptive_reporting_only                  boolean     FALSE                                                                                                
optimizer_adaptive_statistics                      boolean     FALSE                                                                                                
optimizer_capture_sql_plan_baselines               boolean     FALSE                                                                                                
optimizer_dynamic_sampling                         integer     4                                                                                                    
optimizer_features_enable                          string      12.2.0.1                                                                                             
optimizer_index_caching                            integer     0                                                                                                    
optimizer_index_cost_adj                           integer     100                                                                                                  
optimizer_inmemory_aware                           boolean     TRUE                                                                                                 
optimizer_mode                                     string      ALL_ROWS                                                                                             
optimizer_secure_view_merging                      boolean     TRUE                                                                                                 
optimizer_use_invisible_indexes                    boolean     FALSE                                                                                                
optimizer_use_pending_statistics                   boolean     FALSE                                                                                                
optimizer_use_sql_plan_baselines                   boolean     TRUE
```

Comment: I think the problems comes down to the table `D`, and why Oracle thinks it only has one row.  Are there accurate optimizer statistics for that table?  If that table really only has one row then the difference between a full table scan and an index access shouldn't matter.  (Also, are the `Note` sections in the execution plans?  Since this is 12.2 I would expect adaptive plans to play a role here, which should generate an entry in the Note section.)

Comment: Table `D` definitely has more than 1 row (1.3m in production and 1m in test). Note-section of the execution plan is empty. However, the query presented in the topic is minimized subset of the actual query, that exemplifies the problem. If presented query is removed from actual query, the problem does not exist. In the actual query, the execution plan uses dynamic sampling = 4, but that does not affect the presented problem. I'll update the question with our optimizer parameters used.

Comment: If you ran `explain plan for select * from d;` and `select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);` how many rows does Oracle think the table D has?  If the answer is 1 you might want to run `begin dbms_stats.gather_table_stats('SCHEMA_NAME', 'D'); end;` and also investigate why the nightly stats job is not running.

Comment: The plan for `explain plan for select * from D` correclty does index fast full scan on D with 993K rows. Also, I gathered statistics for D, with no change to the execution plan. Oddity 1: if listagg-subquery is commented out, or expansion on or-conditioned join is performed correclty. Oddity 2: if query is run with `/*+ opt_param('_optimizer_cbqt_or_expansion','off') */` to use the pre-12.2 or expansion oracle seems to do the or expansion correctly.